# ELSE Unexpected Error Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this code here and it says that ELSE is unexpected

I have enclosed the else like so )else( and my If statement seems valid to me, but I still have the error message.

Code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e4b9786fbb4f103407f2c35e5437092

Apologies if duplicate, I don't quite understand how to phrase this question differently.

Comment: Post your code herein by [edit] your question! If you have no spaces between the parentheses and `else`, you should try with them...

Comment: You have other issues with your code. I highly advise you read the help for the commands you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space between the `Else` and the `(`

```
:FileCheck
IF exist %dirName% (
    cd %dirName% 
    REM If it exists, change directory
    goto :FileRename
    ) ELSE (
        Rem Else file not found
        ECHO "File not found." 
)
```

Comment: Note that `;` does not denote a comment in batch; the language does not support a comment-to-end-of-line construction. That will cause `"File not found." ;Else file not found` to be emitted to the console.

Comment: I believe it's REM for a comment right? Cause I changed all the ; to REM afterwards.